# Amcharts construct of undefined

Tags: php, jquery, amcharts

Well!!! Sorry for my pour english.
This is my problem with amcharts. I´m doing some graphics in my new proyect.
The proyect is build on MVC and PHP5. 
We did to obtain the results:

//var chartData = AmCharts.loadJSON(baseurl+'libs/jsonvalueconsumption.php?id=...);

Using the Amcharts.loadjson function witch is given on the examples of amcharts.

But now we´re doing via AJAX. The problem????
We got the same results and all the steps of the code are the same but console throws a issue:

Cannot read property 'construct' of undefined amstock.js.pagespeed.ce.sQT2FSFmcG.js:49

This is our js which have to take the graphic on the div:

```
//AmCharts.ready(function() {
    var firstData = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',       
        url: baseurl+'action/charts/SOME_FUNCTION',
        data: { id : id },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        async: false,
        success: function(getdata) {
            return getdata;
        }
    }).responseText;
    chart = new AmCharts.AmStockChart();
    chart.pathToImages = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/images/";
    chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD h:i:s";
    var obj = JSON.parse(firstData);
    for(i=0;i<obj.length;i++) {
        var id_something = obj[i]['id'];
        var secondData = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',       
            url: baseurl+'action/charts/ANOTHER_SOME_FUNCTION',
            data: { id_something : id_something, value1 : value1, value2 : value2 },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            async: false,
            success: function(getdata) {
                return getdata;
            }
        }).responseText;
        var chartData = JSON.parse(secondData);
        var dataSet = new AmCharts.DataSet();
        dataSet.title = obj[i]['name'];
        dataSet.fieldMappings = [{
            fromField: "value",
            toField: "value"
        }, {
            fromField: "volume",
            toField: "volume"
        }];
        dataSet.dataProvider = chartData;
        dataSet.categoryField = "date";
        chart.dataSets.push(dataSet);
    }

    // first stock panel
    var stockPanel1 = new AmCharts.StockPanel();
    stockPanel1.showCategoryAxis = false;
    stockPanel1.title = "Valor";
    stockPanel1.percentHeight = 70;
    // graph of first stock panel
    var graph1 = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
    graph1.valueField = "value";
    graph1.comparable = true;
    graph1.compareField = "value";
    graph1.compareGraphBalloonText="[[value]] kwh"; //mostrar las unidades de medida en el balloon de las comparaciones
    graph1.balloonText= "[[value]] kwh"; //mostrar las unidades de medida en el balloon
    stockPanel1.addStockGraph(graph1);
    // create stock legend                
    stockPanel1.stockLegend = new AmCharts.StockLegend();
    stockPanel1.stockLegend.valueTextRegular="[[value]] kwh"; ////mostrar las unidades de medida en el legend
    // second stock panel
    var stockPanel2 = new AmCharts.StockPanel();
    stockPanel2.title = "Volumen";
    stockPanel2.percentHeight = 30;
    var graph2 = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
    graph2.valueField = "volume";
    graph2.type = "column";
    graph2.showBalloon = false;
    graph2.fillAlphas = 1;
    stockPanel2.addStockGraph(graph2);
    stockPanel2.stockLegend = new AmCharts.StockLegend();
    stockPanel2.stockLegend.valueTextRegular="[[value]] kwh"; ////mostrar las unidades de medida en el legend
    // set panels to the chart
    chart.panels = [stockPanel1, stockPanel2];
    // OTHER SETTINGS ////////////////////////////////////
    var scrollbarSettings = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbarSettings();
    scrollbarSettings.graph = graph1;
    scrollbarSettings.updateOnReleaseOnly = true;
    scrollbarSettings.usePeriod = "10mm";
    chart.chartScrollbarSettings = scrollbarSettings;
    var cursorSettings = new AmCharts.ChartCursorSettings();
    cursorSettings.valueBalloonsEnabled = true;
    chart.chartCursorSettings = cursorSettings;
    // PERIOD SELECTOR ///////////////////////////////////
    var periodSelector = new AmCharts.PeriodSelector();
    periodSelector.periods = [{
        period: "hh",
        count: 24,
        label: "ddd"
    }, {
        period: "hh",
        count: 48,
        label: "dd"
    }, {
        period: "hh",
        count: 120,
        label: "ddd"
    }, {
        period: "hh",
        count: 240,
        label: "dia"
    }, {
        period: "MAX",
        label: "MAX"
    }];
    chart.periodSelector = periodSelector;
    var panelsSettings = new AmCharts.PanelsSettings();
    panelsSettings.usePrefixes = true;
    chart.panelsSettings = panelsSettings;
    // DATA SET SELECTOR
    var dataSetSelector = new AmCharts.DataSetSelector();
    dataSetSelector.position = "left";
    chart.dataSetSelector = dataSetSelector;
    chart.write('chartdiv');
});
```

If someone wants more info or has the solution will be awesome!!!! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I did suffered same error and solution is very simple:

In amCharts folder you'll find three .js files: "amcharts.js", "amstock.js" and "serial.js".

You have to be sure to include them in your html code **IN THIS STRICT SEQUENCE** (here order matters): 
*amcharts.js, serial.js, amstock.js*

That's all ;-)

Comment: this is true. i solve my problem by change the orders like  <script src="../amcharts.js"></script>
 <script src="../../am/serial.js"></script>
 <script src="../amstock.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

AmCharts.loadJSON is not build in method, you should add it yourself, like it is described in this tutorial: http://blog.amcharts.com/2013/09/tutorial-using-php-to-hook-up-charts-to.html